# How to use generics with React.FC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

How to use generics with React.FC ?

code:

```
import React from 'react'

export interface IWaterFallProps<T> {
    className?: string;
    style?: React.CSSProperties;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    dataSource?: T[];
    rowKey?: ((item: T) => string) | string;
    renderItem?: (item: T, index: number) => React.ReactNode;
    header?: React.ReactNode;
    footer?: React.ReactNode;
}


// this T error
const WaterFall: React.FC<IWaterFallProps<T>> = props => {
    return (
        <div 
            className={Styles['waterfall-container']}
            style={props.style}
        >
            {props.header}
            {props.children}
            {props.footer}
        </div>
    )
}

WaterFall.defaultProps = {
    dataSource: [],
}
export default React.memo(WaterFall)
```

> 'const WaterFall: React.FC<IWaterFallProps<T>> = props => {}'

this T is not right, and how to do that it work?

link: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWOYAOxiSk3STgEkB1FJqAMRQAbIQAUcYAM4AeACoA+OAG9ScNXDRCUkyQDkUIJAH4AXHEkwoDAOYBuVeosBPIcbPJ0MAHQBhAMp+4hBgzDDASJL26hoAFsBCACZE9KaIxN4eGLoQCUhR6gm8KH4QAK5QaG5wsgDaALr5ajgA7gDSSE6pABRdwEwgZrIAlHAAvIoWVvTWIwA+5pY2jXDJuVAc-d19SAPVADR09LmUZvSlIABGzCPjaZ5emTDZucsxqGupjw-pz3kOapgIBA+J90t9PL97ABfcikAD0cLgMDikmqcGYOCgpDQEHoFjgPD4ghE7jB-B80m4vGYxLEEhkCkUozgYHpY0UKmiRBg5XocC6-2icGkCWAADd5IKheolKzgpIvG8UGsYdLpbL6V40HFEslVWrohr5V5AcDmPrpdI4aKJYKhqQYaRCTThEIvLlWKUhDAglIxspBYUYMUyhUkGZ6nsHRRqNB4B6UF74F9DCAIF1nQJXUMgA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use normal function declaration

```
function WaterFall<T>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<IWaterFallProps<T>>) {
    // your code
}
```

I've seen tons of hacks and ways to implement this behaviour with "complicated" types and wrappers, but I don't see a need for that when you can use normal function declaration as shown above.

Comment: ```
function WaterFall<T = any>(
    props: PropsWithChildren<IWaterFallProps<T>> & {
        defaultProps?: Partial<IWaterFallProps<T>>;
        displayName?: string;
    },
){
    // your code
}
```

if I hope defaultProps, like above ?